# Torify connection and change exit node programmatically

Tags: php, curl, tor

I am writing a PHP script that basically loops thru some data I have stored in my database. The two main important fields for this project are 'url' and 'country'.

Basically what I am trying to do is loop thru all of these URLs and determine which links are broken (using some PHP resolver, but isn't important to know for this problem). However the issue I am having is that you cannot access a URL that is assigned to a certain country, unless you have an IP address coming from that country. I already have this script set up for U.S URLs because I am here and so it makes that simple.

I was wondering if and how (point me to resources, tips, solutions) I can use Tor to programmatically check this 2 letter country code and go to that URL using that IP. I am guessing it will have something to do with using an Exit Node from that country, but I am not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ExitNodes` configuration option, it is possible to specify exit nodes from a specific country using the syntax `{US}` where US is the country code.

Using the PHP [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils) library this can be automated in a simple way.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php

require 'TorUtils/src/ControlClient.php';
require 'TorUtils/src/TorCurlWrapper.php';

// list of country codes to use
$countries = array('US', 'FR', 'RU', 'GB', 'CA');

// get new control client for connecting to Tor's control port
$tc = new Dapphp\TorUtils\ControlClient();

$tc->connect(); // connect
$tc->authenticate('password'); // authenticate

foreach($countries as $country) {
    $country = '{' . $country . '}'; // e.g. {US}

    $tc->setConf(array('ExitNodes' => $country)); // set config to use exit node from country

    // get new curl wrapped through Tor SOCKS5 proxy
    $curl = new Dapphp\TorUtils\TorCurlWrapper();
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox 41.0');

    // make request - should go through exit node from specified country
    if ($curl->httpGet('http://whatismycountry.com')) {
        echo $curl->getResponseBody();
    }
}
```

TorCurlWrapper is a simple cURL wrapper that routes cURL through the Tor SOCKS5 proxy.  The ControlClient is used to set the configuration option before each request to switch to ExitNodes from a certain country.

Using composer you can install TorUtils:

```
php composer.phar require dapphp/torutils
```

Then in your code use `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to autoload the TorUtils classes.

Comment: Hey drew010, do you have a way I can resolve the url, instead of just get the ResponseBody? I want to grab that ending URL after all the redirects (because my URL will have many). Please, let me know if this is possible

Comment: Assuming `$curl` is your CurlWrapper object, `echo $curl->getInfo()['url'];` should return the final URL used after the redirects.  If that does not work let me know, there is definitely a way to get the redirect url.

Comment: Ok, drew010, I am testing today and will let you know ASAP

Comment: drew010, I am getting an error trying to use your script. here is my code with error message: http://pastebin.com/tK9AXjaM

Comment: @MilanAM This just means the Tor control server isn't running/listening (which it doesn't by default), or it is listening on a port other than 9051 (sometimes 9151 is used).  Make sure the control port is listening and then you should be able to connect.

Comment: drew010 I am sorry I am using Tor for the first time. How do I ensure that Tor control server is listening? Can you point me to some resources to learn about this also?

Comment: @MilanAM See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort  The `ControlPort` directive must be set in torrc and you must set a HashedControlPass or set CookieAuthentication to 1.

Comment: Thank you for the help. So my code is same as that pastebin link above. On my torrc file, I uncommented the 2 lines you suggested like this: http://pastebin.com/kfaceSzp. I am now getting this error: http://pastebin.com/AAjMTf5w Please help I feel like I am close on this project

Comment: Can you post some of the code from TorUrls.php?  For some reason the proxy host and port are showing up as 0.0.0.0:0 but should be something like 127.0.0.1:9050.  These get set in TorCurlWrapper constructor unless they are overridden like `new TorCurlWrapper('proxy_host', 'proxy_port');`

Comment: Yes here you go: http://pastebin.com/8DYa3nsg. I deleted some of my queries but you get the jist of the script

Comment: @MilanAM Thanks for that.  I tested on a fresh VM with a clone of the TorUtils git repo and copied your basic code and was able to get a result back.  Can you run `php -r 'echo PHP_VERSION . " " . curl_version()["version"];'` and tell me the output.  I suspect I know what's going on but not sure.