# Getting the html (requests) works without proxies only (200 vs 404) / (Blocked IP) - Python with Tor

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, request, tor

I had a code snippet that I tried a couple of weeks ago, that was getting the HTML of the page no problem (I was learning about NLP and wanted to try a couple of things with the titles). However, now when I perform a request with proxies (`proxies=session.proxies`) I get`404`. When I omit using the `proxies` everything is fine (that means that I am using my own IP, headers in both cases are identical)... Can someone help me with what is going on here? I am positive that the IPs are blocked. When I use some free proxies from the Internet everything is fine. But they are super unstable, and so it's not possible to do anything. I have also looked at the ips that this code snippet produces:

```
with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate('my_pass')
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait())
```

`2` ips worked (Netherlands and France) from like `20` (Austria, UK, Netherlands (but starts with different two leading digits), Liberia, France (also different two leading digis)) that I have tried so far. **Is it possible to tell tor to use proxies from specific countries?** I guess that wouldn't help me much. If only I could cycle through the working IPs, but I have read somewhere that that is not possible.

Here is the code that preceeds the above code snippet:

```
import requests

global session
session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {}

session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

url = 'https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-news/AAPL.OQ?date=12222016'

html = requests.get(url, timeout=(120, 120), proxies=session.proxies)

print(html)
```

Tried changing user agents to no avail.

Also note, that for the above to work, you need [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

Comment: You can use the `ExitNodes` option to only allow exits from certain countries (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791693/torify-connection-and-change-exit-node-programmatically/33791861#33791861).  Just remember Tor IPs are all known so they may be heavily blocked.  You can cycle through them with NEWNYM signals but there also aren't a huge number of exits available (only ~800), so if you restrict to country you can cycle through them pretty quickly.

Comment: So the solution would be a paid proxy list?

Comment: If you trust the paid proxies are any good, not logging your requests, and aren't banned, maybe. Otherwise spin up a $4 VPS and run your code there.